# "Floating" element taking up space in sibling element, how to make it simply be above?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have tried making all the parents `relative` and this one `absolute`, this does not seem to help, quite at a loss, here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div @mouseover="showList = true">


      <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <v-card class="login-container elevation-12" v-if="showList">
      <div>Some partner IDS</div>
      <div>Some partner IDS</div>
      <div>Some partner IDS</div>
      <div>Some partner IDS</div>
      <div>Some partner IDS</div>
    </v-card>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "DiseaseIDs",
    data: ()=> ({
      showList: false
    }),
    methods: {

    }
  }
</script>
<style>
  .login-container {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    float: left
    /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  }
</style>
```

What this actually looks like is this:
[image]

Comment: Can you publish minimal example in code sandbox?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot its part of a large codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using vuetify `v-menu` there seems to be some issue with vuetify classes and using z-index, it does not give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute;` and `float` won't work together. Decide for one of them.

Comment: removing the `float` does not help

Comment: Yes, it's ignored anyway if you use `position: absolute`. I am not sure what your expected result is, but try to remove the absolute position and keep the float. You can affect the floted elements position by using margin values (for example a negative `margin-left` value to partly make it go out of the parent container)